# javafx fxml LoadException

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, fxml

I am quite new at JavaFx. I am trying to build a simple calculator by following a tutorial . I followed the tutorial step by step . When I run the project , it shows javafx fxml LoadException. I watched some solution relating to this but still I can not fix it. Please help me to fix this error.(Sorry for a long post)

my program files are below

**MainController.java**

```
package application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class MainController {

@FXML
private Label result; // label variable shows output above the buttons, check this
private long number1 = 0;
private String operator = "";
private boolean start = true;
private Model model = new Model();

@FXML
public void processNumbers(ActionEvent event) {
    if (start) {
        result.setText(""); // set the label(output) screen as blank first
        start = false;
    }
    String value = ((Button) event.getSource()).getText(); // take number 1-9 and convert it into String, import the
                                                            // button class otherwise will shows error
    result.setText(result.getText() + value);
}

@FXML
public void processOperators(ActionEvent event) {
    String value = ((Button) event.getSource()).getText();`enter code here`

    if (!value.equals("=")) {
        if (!operator.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        operator = value;
        number1 = Long.parseLong(result.getText());
        result.setText("");
    } else {
        if (operator.isEmpty())
            return;
        long number2 = Long.parseLong(result.getText());
        float output = model.calculate(number2, number2, operator); 

        result.setText(String.valueOf(output));
        start = true;
        }
      }

 }
```

**Model.java**

```
 package application;

public class Model { //for some action event 

    public float calculate(long number1,long number2,String operator) {

    switch(operator) {
        case "+":
            return number1+number2;
        case "-":
            return number1-number2;
        case "*":
            return number1*number2;
        case "/":
            if(number2==0) return 0;
            return number1+number2;
        default:
            return 0;

        }//switch case


    }


}
```

**Main.java**

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.control.*;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Parent root = (Parent) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/CalculatorFxmlFile.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**CalculatorFxmlFile**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="300.0" spacing="10.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.MainController">
   <children>
      <StackPane prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="200.0">
         <children>
            <Label fx:id="result" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="327.0" text="Label">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
         </children></StackPane>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="300.0" spacing="10.0">
         <children>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" prefWidth="50.0" text="7">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" prefWidth="50.0" text="8">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" prefWidth="50.0" text="9">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="result" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperators" prefWidth="50.0" text="/">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="300.0" spacing="10.0">
         <children>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" prefWidth="50.0" text="4">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" prefWidth="50.0" text="5">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" prefWidth="50.0" text="6">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperators" prefWidth="50.0" text="*">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="300.0" spacing="10.0">
         <children>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" prefWidth="50.0" text="1">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" prefWidth="50.0" text="2">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" prefWidth="50.0" text="3">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperators" prefWidth="50.0" text="-">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="300.0" spacing="10.0">
         <children>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" prefWidth="110.0" text="0">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperators" prefWidth="50.0" text="=">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperators" prefWidth="50.0" text="+">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

**Exceptions generated**

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/AllPrograms/Java/eclipse1/CalculatorJavaFx/bin/application/CalculatorFxmlFile.fxml:37

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:15)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javafx.scene.control.Label field application.MainController.result to javafx.scene.control.Button
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.injectFields(FXMLLoader.java:1163)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$1600(FXMLLoader.java:103)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processValue(FXMLLoader.java:857)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:751)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    ... 17 more
```

Comment: You've got 2 elements with `fx:id="result"`

Comment: I removed one and it is working

Answer (score 1):

Here is your error (in your fxml file):

```
<Button fx:id="result" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperators" prefWidth="50.0" text="/">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
```

This button `id` is "result" which is also the id of a label. You should either remove this `id` attribute (I think you missplaced it there) or change it to the one suggested by the tutorial.

**UPDATE**

This operation is division but you are adding the numbers `number1` and `number2`

```
case "/":
    if(number2==0) return 0;
    return number1+number2;
```

so you should perform a division not addition

```
case "/":
    if(number2==0) return 0;
    return number1/number2;
```

**UPDATE 2**

Another error I spotted is also here:

```
float output = model.calculate(number2, number2, operator);
```

You missed the `number1` variable in the `calculate` method:

```
float output = model.calculate(number1, number2, operator);
```

Comment: Fixed by your assistance. But the calculator is not giving me the actual result :( It is producing wrong result @pleft

Comment: Wrong result is a totally different question than the `LoadException` you are asking. However I updated my answer, you have an error in the division operator, you are adding the numbers instead of dividing. At the end you can also accept my answer as correct.

Comment: I would suggest you to re-do your tutorial, I spot many inconsistencies in your code, but I also do not know what exactly you want to achieve, so you'd better take it from the beginning once more.